# Programmatically Create 'full_html' Page Node in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

So I'm able to create a page programmatically, BUT even though I'm specifying the 'full_html' filter, the page is being created with the 'filtered_html' filter which means that the code I'm writing to the page after it's created is being stripped out.  Here's the line I'm using to set the filter type:

```
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
```

Why is the filter type being ignored when the node is created?

Thanks in advance,
Bryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, as it turns out, the 'body' field is not called 'body' in our Drupal installations; it's called 'field_page_body'. Changing that in the code made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be due to the default weight of the filter. You set this in content authoring > input formats

just make "full html" the first option. let me know if that works as I had a similar issue before.

Comment: That worked-- of course, now if I want to create nodes with other filter types, they won't work.  Not sure if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something horribly wrong (although the code above is how it's done in numerous tutorials I've read). Thanks for the workaround-- it may do the trick for me for the time being.

Comment: OK, as it turns out, the 'body' field is not called 'body' in our Drupal installations; it's called 'field_page_body'.  Changing that in the code made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
node_save($node); 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node->nid); 
$wrapper->body->set(array('value' => body_text, 'format'=>'full_html'));
```

hope it's helpful.